# Understanding inheritance on C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, tree

I am trying to design a C++ `Template` class which will contain all the features of a `Tree`(i.e. `appendChild`, `childCount`). I want to then `extend` from this template class and design custom Tree class with existing features (read as `Methods`) as well as extra features.

So far I got this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

/* TREE TEMPLATE CLASS */
template <class T>
class TreeTemplate
{
    public:
        TreeTemplate();
        void appendChild(T*);
        int getChildCount();
    protected:
        std::list<T*> m_childList;
};

/* Constuctor */
template <class T>
TreeTemplate<T>::TreeTemplate(){}

template <class T>
void TreeTemplate<T>::appendChild(T* t)
{
    m_childList.push_back(t);
}

template <class T>
int TreeTemplate<T>::getChildCount()
{
    return m_childList.size();
}

/* CLASS INHERITTING TEMPLATE */
class TreeItem : public TreeTemplate<TreeItem>
{
    public:
        std::string getTestName();
        TreeItem(std::string, std::string);

    private:
        std::string m_testID;
        std::string m_testName;
};

TreeItem::TreeItem(std::string test_id, std::string test_name)
{
    m_testID = test_id;
    m_testName = test_name;
}

std::string TreeItem::getTestName()
{
    return m_testName;
}

/* MAIN FUNCTION */
int main()
{
    TreeItem *myTree = new TreeItem("9", "10");
    TreeItem *child1 = new TreeItem("9.1", "10.1");
    TreeItem *child2 = new TreeItem();

    std::cout << myTree->getTestName() << std::endl;

    myTree->appendChild(child1);
    std::cout << myTree->getChildCount() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I don't try to add some new Constructor in derived class (i.e. contructor `overload`), everything is good. But, if I am adding a new Constructor (as the code segment shows), I am failing to access the existing constructor (of Base Template class). I am getting following error in the line `TreeItem *child2 = new TreeItem();`

[image]

Am I doing something stupid here ? I can overload other methods, only failing at Constructor. How can I overload existing constructor of base template class?

Comment: You'll need to implement a default constructor if you have a custom one, just put `TreeItem(){}` in your `TreeItem` class.

Comment: Just some advice -- why must the user provide a pointer to your `TreeTemplate` class?   If I want to store a plain `int` inside the tree, why do I need to risk memory leaks by doing `new int` for all the integers I want to store?  A good class works with value types -- if the user really wants to store pointers, then they will give your class pointers to store.  For example compare `std::vector<Widget>` and `std::vector<Widget*>`.  If I want pointers to Widget stored, I declare the latter.

Comment: @George, So, as soon as, I declare a new constructor in the derived class, I lose access to the constructor(s) of the base class ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I will definitely go for some careful `delete` calls to free all those pointers in the end of `main`. Just avoided those here to make my main problem easier to understand.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati -- You could duplicate your entire issue with just a [simple example, like this](http://ideone.com/CVXYIH).  Given what you see at that link, do you know how to fix that error?

Comment: @SurajeetBharati -- *I lose access to the constructor(s) of the base class ?* -- No, you have to tell the compiler which base class constructor to invoke using the member-initialization list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to address. The first is that when you define a constructor for a type, that type's default constructor is not implicitly generated. You can force it to be by using `= default`. Here is an example.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;    // Allows default construction
    Foo(int value) : m_value(value) {}
    int m_value;
};
```

The second problem is that a derived type does not inherit it's parent's class' constructors. Intuitively, in the following example, how can a constructor of type `Base` construct an instance of type `Derived`? `Base` is not aware of `Derived`'s members.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int x, int y, int z) : Base(x, y), m_z(z) {}
private:
    int m_z;
};

void foo()
{
    // If we use Base's constructor, what is m_z?
    // Won't compile
    Derived bar(1, 2);
}
```

Only the constructors of the type you are *actually* constructing are eligible, not it's base types' constructors. To simulate the behavior you will have to provide new constructors for the set of parameters you want to support.

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int x, int y, int z) : Base(x, y), m_z(z) {}
    Derived(int x, int y) : Base(x, y), m_z(0) {}
private:
    int m_z;
};
```

In *certain* cases you can work around this problem by supplying a variadic template constructor like the following example. This shouldn't be done in general, only when there is a particular need.

```
#include <utility>

class Base {
public:
    Base(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    template<class ... Args>
    Derived(Args&&... args) : Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {};
};

void foo()
{
    Derived b(1, 2);
}
```